# Showing that f and g's Wronskian satisfies a differential equation and is nonzero everywhere.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I understand that W(f, g)(x) is the determinant of a matrix whose first column is the derivatives of f evaluated at x and whose second column is the derivatives of g evaluated at x. However, I'm stuck because I don't know how to evaluate it since we aren't given information about f and g.

[image: image of problem]

Comment: Could you reproduce the problem you're trying to solve on this site? The main content of a post should not be in a link.

Answer (score 1):

The Wronskian is given by
$$W(x) = \begin{vmatrix}f(x)&g(x)\\f'(x)&g'(x) \end{vmatrix} = f(x)g'(x) - f'(x)g(x). $$
Computing its derivative, we have
\begin{align}
W'(x) &= f'(x)g'(x) + f(x)g''(x) -f''(x)g(x) - f'(x)g'(x)\\
&= f(x)g''(x) - f''(x)g(x).
\end{align}
It follows that
\begin{align}
p(x)W'(x) +q(x)W(x) &= p(x)(f(x)g''(x) - f''(x)g(x)) + q(x)(f(x)g'(x) - f'(x)g(x))\\
&= f(x)(p(x)g''(x) + q(x) g'(x)) - g(x) (p(x)f''(x) +q(x)f'(x))\\
\end{align}
Now, since $f$ and $g$ satisfy the original ODE, we have
\begin{align}
p(x)f''(x) + q(x)f'(x) &= -r(x)f(x)\\
p(x)g''(x) + q(x)g'(x) &= -r(x)g(x),
\end{align}
and hence
$$ 
p(x)W'(x) + q(x)W(x) = f(x)(-r(x)g(x)) - g(x)(-r(x)f(x)) = 0.
$$

The equation $pW' + qW=0$ is a first-order linear differential equation, and you should be familiar with the proof that its general solution is $ke^{-\int\frac{q(t)}{p(t)}\ \mathsf dt}$ (if not, then this is a good exercise). It follows immediately that $W(x)\ne0$ for any $x$, since the exponential function $x\mapsto \exp(x)$ is strictly positive.

Comment: And there are many explanations of part (b) on Stackexchange, for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176449/is-there-another-method-to-solve-this-differential-equation/1176459#1176459